# Como faço para exibir todas as colunas do meu BD asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, mvc

queria saber como faço para dar um loop na hora de imprimir as colunas da minha grid com os valores do banco de dados, porem ele exibi apenas 1 resultado mesmo o banco de dados sendo enorme, aqui esta o código, obrigado pelo ajuda

CONTROLLER:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TelerikMvcApp1.Models;


namespace TelerikMvcApp1.Controllers
{
    public partial class GridController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult GetContacts()
          {
            SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(@"meubancodedados");
            conexao.Open();

            string strQuerySelect = "SELECT * FROM PessoaFisica";
            SqlCommand cmdComandoSelect = new SqlCommand(strQuerySelect, conexao);
            SqlDataReader dados = cmdComandoSelect.ExecuteReader();

            while (dados.Read())
            {

            var contacts = new List<OrderViewModel>
                  {

                      new OrderViewModel {CompanyName = "Alabaster Almonds", ContactName = "Alex Allentown", Nome = dados["nome"].ToString()},
                  };
                return Json(contacts);
            }
                return GetContacts();
          }
    }
}
```

VIEW:

```
@model TelerikMvcApp1.Models.OrderViewModel
@using TelerikMvcApp1.Models

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<OrderViewModel>()
                .Name("ExampleGrid")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(c => c.ContactName).Width(140);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.CompanyName);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Nome);
                })
                .DataSource(s => s.Ajax().Read(r => r.Action("GetContacts", "Example")))
)
<script>

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Grid/GetContacts",
        dataType: "json",
        data:{data:'B'},
        success: function (data) {
            $("#ExampleGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(data);
        },
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece porque você cria uma lista a cada laço e tenta retornar esta lista **ainda dentro do laço**. Isso vai fazer com que o fluxo termine ainda no primeiro laço `while`.

O correto seria adicionar um item a uma lista existente a cada *loop* e só retornar depois **de todos os laços**.

```
var contacts = new List<OrderViewModel>();

while (dados.Read())
{   
     contacts.Add(new OrderViewModel 
     {
         CompanyName = "Alabaster Almonds", 
         ContactName = "Alex Allentown", 
         Nome = dados["nome"].ToString()
     });            
}

return Json(contacts);
```

Comment: mesmo assim minha view nao aparece nada na lista, mesmo o banco de dados tendo coisas para ler, o loop ainda nao funciona.

Comment: @MarceloHenriqueDosReis Aí é porque você fez algo errado...

Comment: agora que vi que o problema na view era outro coisa, seu codigo estava certo, vlwzao <3